# Print number of iteration with forM in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was wondering how I can print the number of iterations done.
I thought about using an another lambda function inside such as `(\a succ)`, failing.

This is my code

```
showit = forM list (\a -> putStr "number:"++HEREWHAT??++" is "++" a"
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what your code does. Is there more than a `)` missing? What type is `board`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enumerate items of the list using `zipWithM`:

```
display = zipWithM (\i a -> putStr "number:" ++ show i ++ " is " ++ a) [1,2..] board
```

(or enumerate with [0,1..] if you want to count from zero).